# How to select from table limit per column same values X results

Tags: mysql, sql

My table is:

```
id   uid  art_id  
---|-----|--------
1  | 10  |  11   |
2  | 11  |  23   | 
5  | 10  |  16   | 
3  | 10  |  13   | 
4  | 11  |  59   | 
6  | 11  |  36   |
7  | 11  |  55   | 
8  | 13  |  68   |
```

I need to select from the table two results art_id from each uid but maximally two in row order.

Update: I have a big database with CCA 19m rows, need to select last two articles from each user (limit users 200 per SQL request). Order by uid

Result would be:

```
id   uid  art_id  
---|-----|--------
1  | 10  |  11   |
5  | 10  |  16   | 
2  | 11  |  23   | 
4  | 11  |  59   | 
8  | 13  |  68   | 
3  | 10  |  13   |
6  | 11  |  36   | 
7  | 11  |  55   |
```

Comment: . . I don't get your question.  Your desired results have more than two rows for users.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MOD (ROW_NUM, 2) + TRUNC (ROW_NUM, 2) AS GROUPBY2,
     ROW_NUM,
     ID,
     UID,
     ART_ID
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER ()
                OVER (PARTITION BY UID ORDER BY UID DESC)
                ROW_NUM,
             ID,
             UID,
             ART_ID
        FROM TABLE )
ORDER BY GROUPBY2
```